# Extracting content using JSOUP

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm having trouble extracting web content using Jsoup. The problem is that- I'm getting more than what I needed !. Here is the format of web content..

```
<td>
 <ul>
  <li>
       <b>
        Title
        </b>  
     contents     
        <p>
           <a href="www.somesite.com"><b>LinkText</b></a>
        </p>
  </li>
 </ul>
</td>
```

I'm trying to extract title , content and linkText seperately.. 
Taking LinkText wasn't tough . I used this code to take that data

```
String title = "";
Elements elements;
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
elements = document.select("td ul li p a");
for (Element e : elements) 
title += "\n" + e.text() + "\n\n";
```

When I tries to take the Content with this code.

```
String content = "";
Elements elements;
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
elements = document.select("td ul li");
for (Element e : elements) 
content += "\n" + e.text() + "\n\n";
```

I'm getting everything. (Title, Content, LinkText). The reason for this problem is because all three items are inside `<li>` .So it is returing every texts inside.. So , how can I get them as distinct Strings. I also want to get the Link- www.www.somesite.com along with the data..

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selectorgadget/mhjhnkcfbdhnjickkkdbjoemdmbfginb consider using this tool, it tells you the exact css selector for the item you choose.

Comment: i'm working on an android app

Comment: no problem, css selectors are not platform dependent :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Jsoup documentation the `text()` method gets combined text of selected element and **all** its children.

What you should to do is to use the `ownText()` method which gets ONLY the text owned by selected element.

Answering your second question: to get the `href` attribute of `<a>` tag use: `element.attr("href")`.

Whole thing should look as follows:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
String title = document.select("td ul li b").first().text();
String content = document.select("td ul li").first().ownText();
Element linkEl = document.select("td ul li p a").first();
String href = linkEl.attr("href");
String link = linkEl.text();
```

See:

- https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText--
- https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#attr-java.lang.String-